# Twitter API Interactions timeline

Tags: api, twitter, timeline

It is possible to get timeline like [Twitter / Interactions](https://twitter.com/#!/i/connect) through Twitter API?

I mean, timeline, witch contains who follow me, who mention me, who reply to me, who retwited me and who unfollow me (ALL with dates of action).

Comment: I know, how to get followers, etc.
The main problem, it to know WHEN he follow me (right like in page https://twitter.com/#!/i/connect, https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169523), WHEN someone reply my tweet, etc.

Comment: There was undocumented API method but it's also unavailable since API 1.0 is gone.